# DynamicObject's TryConvert is not being called for limited-visibility type

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics, dynamicobject

I wonder why does changing visiblity of DynamicObject-derived class to private prevent the framework from calling TryConvert.

I.e. following code outputs like this:

```
Calling TryGetMember
Calling TryConvert
```

But if I change

```
public sealed class DynamicJsonObject
```

to private (it's nested within DynamicJsonConverter), then it's

```
Calling TryGetMember
InvalidCastException is thrown
```

(Unable to cast object of type 'DynamicJsonObject' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]

at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object ) at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0))

Code:

```
void Main()
{
   var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() });

   dynamic result = serializer.Deserialize("{ 'response' : { 'data' : '1', 's' : -1 } }", typeof(object));
   ((IDictionary<string, object>)result.response).Dump();
}

public sealed class DynamicJsonConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");

        return type == typeof(object) ? new DynamicJsonObject(dictionary) : null;
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<Type>(new List<Type>(new[] { typeof(object) })); }
    }

    public sealed class DynamicJsonObject : DynamicObject
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<string, object> _dictionary;       

        public DynamicJsonObject(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
        {
            if (dictionary == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");
            _dictionary = dictionary;
        }

        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calling TryGetMember");
            if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result))
            {
                result = null;
                return true;
            }
            var dictionary = result as IDictionary<string, object>;
            if (dictionary != null)
            {
                result = new DynamicJsonObject(dictionary);
                return true;
            }
            var arrayList = result as ArrayList;
            if (arrayList != null && arrayList.Count > 0)
            {
                if (arrayList[0] is IDictionary<string, object>)
                    result = new List<object>(arrayList.Cast<IDictionary<string, object>>().Select(x => new DynamicJsonObject(x)));
                else
                    result = new List<object>(arrayList.Cast<object>());
            }
            return true;
        }

        public override bool TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calling TryConvert");
            result = null;
            if (binder.Type == typeof(IDictionary<string, object>))
            {
                result = _dictionary;
                return true;
            }           
            return base.TryConvert(binder, out result);
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the stack trace from the InvalidCastException please.

Comment: Here you go: at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)